# What is the extension of a polynomial from a discrete sum of integer-order terms to a continuous integral of real-order terms?

Tags: real-analysis

If a polynomial function on the reals can be generalized as $$p:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R},\ p(x) = \sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}^\ a(n) \cdot x^n$$

where $a:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, could you extend it to something rather like
$$f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R},\ f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty a(k) \cdot x^k\ dk$$

where $a:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$? (Perhaps not this specifically, I thought this was a generalization of a power series, the comments showed me I was very wrong)

Has this been studied at all? What field would this be? I'm guessing it's real analysis but I've only had one undergrad class in it.

Comment: I mean... you could look at it, I guess, but it doesn't seem to generalise the notion of a power series (You can't choose your $a(k)$'s in the integral expression so that the whole thing becomes an infinite sum).

Comment: Are you sure? You'd just need $\forall k \notin \mathbb{Z},\ a(k)=0$

Comment: No. If $a(k)=c_k$ for $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $0$ otherwise, then $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} a(k) x^k \textrm{d}k=0$.

Comment: Ah. Of course. I knew I had to be missing something. I'll edit the question accordingly.

Comment: What if $a(k)$ was a function locally equal to some Dirac function $\delta_a(k)$ near all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$? Would the range be a problem?

Comment: The Dirac $\delta$ isn't a function, but sure, defining $f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} a(k) x^k\textrm{d}\mu(k)$ for a general measure $\mu$ *does* generalise the notion of power series.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104170/discussion-between-neph-and-woolierthanthou).